# mysql.jdbc.driver class not found exception

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, classpath

I am building an app which connect to MySQL database using intelij idea. I have imported jdbc driver through modules > dependencies and it works great when I run the app through IDE. But when I build an artifact using build > build artifacts > rebuild (tried clean and build also) and I ran it using cmd I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding project but it didnt help.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. Intelij idea was not adding new library dependency to artifact build path. So the solution is to recreate artifact and then module dependency is added. Or just add it manualy to artifact settings

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver JAR file needs to be on the classpath when you run the code.  For example, if you are running your application like:

```
java -jar Application.jar
```

You should use:

```
java -classpath /path/to/Driver.jar -jar Application.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use maven, it resolve all dependencies for you.
In IDEA you can start maven project:
**File->New->Project: chose Maven**

You don't need to search & place your dependency jars in classpath manually, just add another one dependency in pom.xml and maven download it for you.

[image]

To know which dependency snippet you need you - just search it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=mysql)